# How to achieve atomicity in Mongo DB?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have 2 different scenarios.

1)  I want to update 2 documents same time or none incase of failure of first document save/update. What kind of atomicity feature does MongoDB provides?
2)  I want to update (overwrite) a document with latest data keeping same index/primary key. Currently I am doing this by deleting an existing document and again creating one with same index key, how can I achieve this without deleting existing document with same index key?

Comment: Have you read the docs on [atomicity](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/write-operations-atomicity/) and [document replacement](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#replace-a-document-entirely)?

Comment: 1) Condition will be always "None", since there is no such thing as transactions. Adjust your model so that the two values you need to change are contained in the same document. 2) findAndModify or update are your friends.